# Não consigo fazer essa push no github

Tags: git, github

sempre está dando esse erro. (Já dei o comando $ git pull origin master).

! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Breno948/calculadora-react.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Answer (score 0):

Tente esse comando forçando o push

```
git push -f origin master
```

Com a tag -f você irá substituir o conteúdo da branch remota pelo código que você tem no seu repositório local

Comment: Meu deus, finalmente uma solução! obrigado irmão!!